# Include theorem name from thmtools into mdframed title box

Tags: theorems, mdframed, thmtools

[mdframed](/questions/tagged/mdframed) is nice for controlling the outer layout of theorems. [thmtools](/questions/tagged/thmtools) on the other hand can take care of a number of other things great and small, in particular the detailed formatting of the title within the flow of text, but also stuff like maintaining a flexible list of theorems, properly setting autoref names, and so on. I know I can use the `mdframed` key to the `\declaretheorem` command to let it create a frame and control most aspects of that frame. What I'm missing, though, is a way to make use of the `frametitle` facilities of [mdframed](/questions/tagged/mdframed) in this way.

**Is there a way to redirect the title typesetting commands from [thmtools](/questions/tagged/thmtools) into the `frametitle` argument to the `mdframed` environment it creates?**

I see that I can add a hook before and a hook after the title, but at least my naive way of capturing the title between these two using `\def\myframetitle\bgroup` and `\egroup` failed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,tikz,geometry,amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{thm-patch}% copied from thmdef-mdframed.sty
\makeatletter
\mdfdefinestyle{fstyle}{linecolor=blue,frametitlerule=true}
% The following was adapted from thmdef-mdframed.sty but does not work:
\define@key{thmdef}{mymdframed}[{}]{%
  \thmt@trytwice{}{%
    \addtotheorempreheadhook[\thmt@envname]{%
      \def\myframetitle\bgroup}%
    \addtotheorempostheadhook[\thmt@envname]{%
      \egroup\begin{mdframed}[frametitle=\myframetitle,#1]}%
    \addtotheorempostfoothook[\thmt@envname]{\end{mdframed}}%
    }%
}
% Change the mymdframed to mdframed to make this compile at all:
\declaretheoremstyle[mymdframed={style=fstyle}]{tstyle}
\declaretheorem[style=tstyle]{thm}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}[Round] The world is round\end{thm}

And this is what it \emph{should} look like:
\begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Thm 1: Round},style=fstyle]
The world is round\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

I'll be happy to learn about *any* approach to get the two packages working together including the title. There must be *some* solution, e.g. by defining your own wrapper macros to handle the title argument, but I hope for some more elegant approaches from those who know more.

Comment: You can use `\mdtheorem[style=fstyle]{thm}{Thm}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Not using `thmtools`, I get warnings from `hyperref` about a missing autoref name for `Thm`. Furthermore, I can't control the formatting of the heading as well, e.g. I can't use different fonts for the theorem number and its name. I'm also worried about the list of theorems facilities, although I haven't tried them with `mdtheorem` alone.

Comment: let me have a closer look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try to provide an answer.

`thmtools` uses the default environment provided by `amsthm`. To use `mdframed` with `frametitle` you have to redefine the default environment of `amsthm`. However I don't know whether it's a good idea. With the simple test file below it works. Please note that all theorem environments are enclosed by `mdframed`.

In the example I also show how to modify the style of `mdframed`:

```
\setcounter{errorcontextlines}{999}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,tikz,geometry,amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools,thm-patch}% copied from thmdef-mdframed.sty
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\makeatletter

\def\@thm#1#2#3{%
%  \ifhmode\unskip\unskip\par\fi
  \normalfont
  \let\thmheadnl\relax
  \let\thm@swap\@gobble
  \thm@notefont{\fontseries\mddefault\upshape}%
  \thm@headpunct{.}% add period after heading
  \thm@headsep 5\p@ plus\p@ minus\p@\relax
  \thm@space@setup
  #1% style overrides
  \@topsep \thm@preskip               % used by thm head
  \@topsepadd \thm@postskip           % used by \@endparenv
  %
  \def\@tempa{#2}\ifx\@empty\@tempa
    \def\@tempa{\@oparg{\@begintheorem{#3}{}}[]}%
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#2}%
    \def\@tempa{\@oparg{\@begintheorem{#3}{\csname the#2\endcsname}}[]}%
  \fi
  \@tempa
}
\def\@begintheorem#1#2[#3]{%
    \mdframed[style=fstyle,frametitle={%
    \the\thm@headfont \thm@indent
    \@ifempty{#1}{\let\thmname\@gobble}{\let\thmname\@iden}%
    \@ifempty{#2}{\let\thmnumber\@gobble}{\let\thmnumber\@iden}%
    \@ifempty{#3}{\let\thmnote\@gobble}{\let\thmnote\@iden}%
    \thm@swap\swappedhead\thmhead{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    \the\thm@headpunct}]%
  }%

\def\@endtheorem{\endmdframed}
\makeatother


\mdfdefinestyle{fstyle}{linecolor=blue,frametitlerule=true,linewidth=2pt,}
\declaretheoremstyle[notefont=\itshape,preheadhook={\mdfapptodefinestyle{fstyle}{backgroundcolor=gray}}]{tstyle}
\declaretheorem[style=tstyle]{thm}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}[Round] The world is round\end{thm}

And this is what it \emph{should} look like:

\begin{thm}The world is round\end{thm}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please test it before you use it!

Comment: That took some doing.